# traverse of tree in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript variable like below:

```
 var treeNode= [{"id":"T1"},{"id":"T2","children":[{"id":"T3"},{"id":"T4"},{"id":"T5","children":[{"id":"T6"}, {"id":"T7"},{"id":"T8"}]},{"id":"T9"},{"id":"T10"}]},{"id":"T11"},{"id":"T12"}];
```

node t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10 are the child of node t2
 i have a link of deactivate on each node.on click on deactivate link make active and delete link .mentioned in image.
[image]

now i want to make same active and delete link on all child node of parent node.
for example T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10 are the child of T2.
if i click on T5 then this will work on T6,T7,T8.

I tried below recursive code.may be my approach is not right.please advice.

```
var objTreeNode = eval(treeNode);
trav(objTreeNode); 
function trav(TreeNodeObj){
    var i=0;
    for (i=0;i<TreeNodeObj.length;i++){

        if(!TreeNodeObj[i].children){
            if(objID==TreeNodeObj[i].id){ // will get T2 if click on deactivate link of Item T2
            document.getElementById('span_'+TreeNodeObj[i].id).innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:activate(\'' + objID + '\');">Activate</a>    <a href="javascript:deleteNode(\'' + objID
            +'\');">Delete</a>';
            }
        }
        else{
            childObj = TreeNodeObj[i].children;
            trav(childObj)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few silly things in your code, let me fix them:

**1. "Eval is evil!"**

```
var treeNode= [{"id":"T1"},{"id":"T2","children":[{"id":"T3"}]}];
var objTreeNode = eval(treeNode);
trav(objTreeNode);
```

Why would you call eval()?
Let's see what MDN has to say about this:

- [Don't use eval!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21) It's dangerous and slow. `There are safe (and fast!) alternatives to eval() for common use-cases.`

  So what is your "use-case"? Why do you call eval here? What is the "better" solution? If you read the whole documentation on MDN you can read that:
- `If the argument of eval() is not a string, eval() returns the argument unchanged.`

  So unless `treeNode` is a string `var objTreeNode = eval(treeNode);` basically equals to `var objTreeNode = treeNode;`

You can drop that whole eval() line and just use treeNode. It's already an object.

**2. camelCase**

```
function trav(TreeNodeObj) {
```

This is not an error just a convention: In JavaScript (and also in most languages with C-like syntax) the parameters of a function are written with [lower camel case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) (first letter is lowercase, and every other word's first letter is uppercase).

```
function trav(treeNodeObj) {
```

**3. objID is undefined**

There is no objID variable defined in your code. Although it is possible that you have a global defined elsewhere at the given time, it is much safer to introduce it as a parameter in your function.

```
function trav(treeNodeObj, objID) {
```

**4. What your code does with what and when**

Let me just figure out what your code currently does:

- Iterates over a given object's children property (which is hopefully an array).

  - If an element has no children

    - Check if the array item has a desired ID property, and change it's innerHTML
  - Else

    - Call the function on the children

So what it does: Changes the element with the given ID if it has no children.

What you need is: Change the element with the given ID and also it's children.

I just modified your function like this:

```
function trav(treeNodeObj, objID, activate) {
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < treeNodeObj.length; i++) {
        var childrenActive = false;

        if (objID === treeNodeObj[i].id || activate) { // will get T2 if click on deactivate link of Item T2
            childrenActive = true;
            document.getElementById('span_' + treeNodeObj[i].id).innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:activate(\'' + objID + '\');">Activate</a>    <a href="javascript:deleteNode(\'' + objID + '\');">Delete</a>';
        }

        if (treeNodeObj[i].children) {
            childObj = treeNodeObj[i].children;
            trav(childObj, objID, childrenActive);
        }
    }
}
```

Since you need to change all the child elements I needed to introduce a cut. This is the activate parameter. If the activate parameter is true you don't need to check the ID anymore you know that we are iterating over the subelements of the element with the given ID, and therefore change the element anyway.

Also you need to change the elements even if they have child nodes, so I restructured the if-s.

I have also made a jsfiddle for you to test: http://jsfiddle.net/JZ52g/3/

You can change the id parameter at the function call.