# Traverse of a tree in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a variable in javascript  like below:

```
var treeNode = [{
    "id": "T1"
  }, {
    "id": "T2",
    "children": [{
        "id": "T3"
      }, {
        "id": "T4"
      }, {
        "id": "T5",
        "children": [{
            "id": "T6"
          }, {
            "id": "T7"
          }, {
            "id": "T8"
          }
        ]
      }, {
        "id": "T9"
      }, {
        "id": "T10"
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "id": "T11"
  }, {
    "id": "T12"
  }
];
```

Node t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10 are the child of node t2.

each node has a link of deactivate .when click on deactivate two link active and delete create.mentioned in image:

[image]

i want to create same active and delete link on all child node of parent node.for example
if i click on deactivate link of T5 then active and delete link will show on T6,T7,T8 also
and
if i click on deactivate link of T2 then active and delete link will show on T3,T4,T5, T6,T7,T8,T9,T10 also

I tried below recursive code.but i think this is not a right approach.please advice.

```
var objTreeNode = eval(treeNode);
trav(objTreeNode);

function trav(TreeNodeObj){
    var i=0;
    for (i=0;i<TreeNodeObj.length;i++){
        if(!TreeNodeObj[i].children){
            if(objID==TreeNodeObj[i].id(){ //if click on T2 then get T2 as objID
                document.getElementById('span_'+objID).innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:activate(\'' + objID + '\');">Activate</a>    <a href="javascript:deleteNode(\'' + objID
                Delete</a>';
            }
        }
        else{

            childObj = TreeNodeObj[i].children;

            trav(objTreeNode)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post some working example ? And then mention the problem?. Because it's hard to understand the business mentioned. It would be helpful if you post some example.

Comment: Your recursive code has a syntax error.

Comment: Why did you ask the same question twice and then never accepted or commented on any of the answers? Also you only ever accepted 1 answer for your 10 questions so far, and even the accepted answer is a really silly one (converting an object to a string then evaling it back into an object).

Comment: possible duplicate of [traverse of tree in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917487/traverse-of-tree-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Your traversal code is wrong, the basic traversal should look like

```
function trav(obj) {
    // do something with obj

    //traverse through the children and call trav for each child
    if (obj.children) {
        for (i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++) {
            trav(obj.children[i])
        }
    }

}
```

I'm assuming during de-activation of an item, you want to deactivate all its children also, in that case try something like

```
var treeMap = {};
for (i = 0; i < TreeNodeObj.length; i++) {
    var obj = TreeNodeObj[i];
    treeMap[obj.id] = obj;
}

function deactivate(obj) {
    if (typeof obj == 'string') {
        obj = treeMap[obj];
    }
    document.getElementById('span_' + obj.id).innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:activate(\''
            + obj.id
            + '\');">Activate</a>    <a href="javascript:deleteNode(\''
            + obj.id + 'Delete</a>';

    if (obj.children) {
        for (i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++) {
            deactivate(obj.children[i])
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your recursion code should be [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/6xLq2/):

```
function trav(node) {

    var i;

    //deactivate target node
    console.log('Deactivating node id: '+node.id);

    //do the same to it's children
    if(node.children){
        for(i=0;i<node.children.length;i++){
          trav(node.children[i]);  
        } 
    }

}

console.log('Kill T1');
trav(objTreeNode[0]); //T1

console.log('Kill T2');
trav(objTreeNode[1]); //T2

console.log('Kill T5');
trav(objTreeNode[1].children[2]); //T5
```

Just swap out the `console.log` part of `trav` with your operation that indicates deactivation. The sample shows the correct nodes targetted in the console (press <kbd>F12</kbd>)